# How can I customize the look of the GridViewHeaderRowPresenter in a Custom Listview Style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, styles

I want to create a custom ListView style starting from the default style present in Aero. I removed all the aero bull code and am left with only the basic stuff, but now, I would like to customize the look of the headers of the listview

```
GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
```

The style of this element has to be customized so that it looks the way i want. However, it seems I cannot do it. I tried replacing it with a

```
GridViewColumnHeader
```

But then all the bindings are gone. Any tips ?

Comment: If you style the `GridViewColumnHeader` and now the bindings are gone you probably did something wrong, but unless you post the code we cannot help you.

Comment: thanks ! I managed to find out what was wrong. I was using

Answer (score 0):

thanks ! I managed to find out what was wrong. I was using '' and in my test-app it worked. However, when trying to use the same style in the actual application, it was either overwritten or not used. So i tried something like Style x:Key="Style_GridViewColumnHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}". That worked, but for some reason, the padding does not apply. this is the code i used for the padding part:

```
     <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Padding">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BRUSH_ListView_HeaderBorderBorderBrush_ALL}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="{DynamicResource BRUSH_ListView_HeaderBorderBackground_UP}">
                            <Border x:Name="borderHighlight" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BRUSH_ListView_borderHighlightBorderBrush_UP}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```